# C# ¿Como Convertir string a System.IO.StreamWriter?

Tags: c#, mvc, razor

Hola tengo el siguiente problema quiero escribir mi csv pero ponía mal los acentos con caracteres extraños. Entonces quiero agregar UTF8 pero al ponerle , mas Encoding.UTF8 ya me dice que

> No se puede convertir string a System.IO.Stream

```
    using (System.IO.StreamWriter escritor = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\NUEVO\Desktop\xd\mylittlepony.csv", Encoding.UTF8))

                    {
                        escritor.WriteLine("Nombre,Email,Compania,Web,Direccion,Telefono,Giro");
                    }
```

Si yo pongo esta parte sin `Encoding.UTF8` en esta parte funciona pero con caracteres extraños.

```
using (System.IO.StreamWriter escritor = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\NUEVO\Desktop\xd\mylittlepony.csv"))
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Estás usando mal la sobrecarga, se requieren 3 parámetros para ese caso

```
new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\NUEVO\Desktop\xd\mylittlepony.csv", false, Encoding.UTF8)
```

El booleano indica si quieres que encime el archivo (false) o si quieres que agrege el contenido a lo ya existente (true)

Comment: Estaba a punto de publicar la misma respuesta. Fuente: [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/f5f5x7kt(v=vs.110).aspx).